# JavaFX imput in textfields

Tags: javafx

Estou fazendo um programa de calcular matrizes, mas não sei como por uma ação para o botão "Confirmar" para pegar os valores digitados das TextLabels (tl_linhas e tl_colunas) e passar para as variaveis Int x e Int Y.

```
package matrizes;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {


    @FXML
    private TextField tf_linhas;

    @FXML
    private Button btnTexto;

    @FXML
    private Button btnLC;

    @FXML
    private TextField tf_colunas;

    @FXML
    private final AnchorPane apMatriz = new AnchorPane();

      public void btnLC(ActionEvent e){


      }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i < x+1; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j < y+1; j++){
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.setPrefWidth(40);
                btn.setLayoutX(i*45);
                btn.setLayoutY(j*30);
                btn.setText("a"+i+""+j);
            apMatriz.getChildren().add(btn);
            }
        }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A ação desejada pode ser implementada no método `setOnMouseClicked` do botão, dessa forma:

```
btn.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
    x = Integer.parseInt(tlLinhas.getText());
    y = Integer.parseInt(tlColunas.getText());
});
```

Contudo, as variáveis x e y terão que se tornar variáveis de classe. O java não permite utilizar variáveis locais em uma inner class, a não ser que a variável seja final.